# Incrementally Read Large Multipart Zipped Text File in Python

Tags: python, parsing, stream, zip

I have a very large zip file that is split into multiple parts as split archives, with a single file within the archive. I do not have enough resources to combine these archives together or extract them (the raw text file is nearly 1TB).

I would like to parse the text file line by line, ideally using something like this:

```
import zipfile
for zipfilename in filenames:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename) as z:
        with z.open(...) as f:
            for line in f:
                print line
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I read the text file:

1. Without using too much memory (loading the whole file into memory is obviously out of the question)
2. Without extracting any of the zip files
3. (Ideally) Without combining the zip files

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: wow thats an incredibly large text file, how many parts do you have in zip files? and why is it that big?

Comment: It is possible, but I'm pretty sure if you do it in Python you will also need a cryogenic time chamber on hand to wait in, considering it will take a looong time to complete.  That, or get a large cluster.

Comment: There will probably be over 3500 parts, and yes it's huge. It's a research dataset, and contains the full text content of 10 million or so research papers.

Comment: @AdamBarthelson, I don't need most of the content, so I'm hoping it will not be terribly inefficient. I think 99% of the lines can just be skipped.

Comment: What information do you need exactly?

Comment: You did not clarify what you mean by "large zip file that is split into multiple parts". Do you mean: 1. literally `zip | split`; or 2. the zip format's "split archive" as in `zip -s`, which could or could not be the same thing as 1. (I haven't checked); or 3. separate zip archives of every chunk split from the huge file; or something else entirely?

Comment: By the way, if your zips are proper "split archives" according to the Zip file format, you won't be able to read them with either Python's zipfile library nor with the unzip terminal command (which would otherwise be useful for its -p "pipe" option, as in `unzip -p archive.zip filename | process_line_by_line`)

Comment: @Tobia thanks for pointing that out, I didn't think of how that could be interpreted. It is split archives I believe, with a single file to be read from all parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take a stab.

If your zip files are the so-called "split archives" according to the Zip file format, you won't be able to read them either with Python's zipfile library nor with the `unzip` terminal command.

If, on the other hand, you are dealing with a single zip archive that has been split using the `split` command or a similar byte-splitting device, you might be able to extract and read its contents on the fly in Python.

You will have to write a "file-like" custom class that will accept the seek() and read() methods (and possibly others) and perform them on the split chunks.

seek() will need to compute which zip file to read, open it (if it's not the current file still open) and perform a seek() on it using the difference in offsets.

read() will read from the chunk that is currently open, dealing with the End of file condition, which will cause it to open the next chunk and complete the read on it.

After you write and test this class, it will just be a matter of calling the ZipFile constructor passing an instance of your class as the "virtual zip" file object to open.